# In the given example, what is the logic behind the use of the Random class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, random

The method below creates a one-dimensional array of type int of a given size and randomly assigns the value 1 to a given percentage of the array. I don't completely understand the use of nextInt in this example. How is it made sure that in every iteration of the while loop a different index is chosen and not an index that was already chosen in a previous iteration.

```
import java.util.Random;

...

    int[] randomIntArray(int size, double percent) {
        int n = (int) (size * percent);
        int[] array = new int[size];
        Random r = new Random();

        while(n > 0) {
            int next = r.nextInt(size);
            if (array[next] != 0) continue;
            array[next] = 1;
            n--;
        }

        return array;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's fine when `next` was previously selected, as there is a `if (array[next] != 0)` check followed by `array[next] = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

The line `if (array[next] != 0) continue;` clearly (as clearly as poorly formatted code can) states, that if the array index' value already has been set to 1 to go straight back to the head of the while loop.

The `continue` keyword should be used with great care and only sparingly because it's not very reader friendly and there are usually better ways to archieve the same goal..

Comment: So it goes back to the head of the while loop before it decrements?